# C programming language equivalent for structure initialization in C++

Tags: c++, c, struct

Assuming list is some structure

```
list *temp;
temp = new list;
```

the above is in c++, does this have an equivalent in C?

Comment: There are no real ways to achieve this because c is not object oriented so you cannot have constructors but you can create functions that initialize structs and return its pointer as a contructor would

Comment: In C, I'd do it this way:  `list* temp; temp = malloc(sizeof(list)); list_init(temp);`

Comment: I like `list *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);`. That way if you ever change it from a list to something else, there's less code to change, and it's in general less error prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```c
list *temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof(list));

[...]

free(temp);
```

C doesn't have the `new` keyword - you've got to allocate and free the memory you'd like to use manually. `new` also does some [work behind the scenes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/malloc-vs-new/), like calling constructors and returning the proper pointer type - `malloc` doesn't cover that, and has to be handled by the programmer.

Comment: Don't cast malloc's return in C.

Comment: Your comment lead me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/7431860); I have learned something new. Thank you!